# Comparing array to string PHP

Tags: php

I want to check if the data is match between array and the string.
Im trying to check if the string is equals to each other but the problem is the condition is returning false and both value of `$subex2[1]` and `$subdat` is `IT100`. I think the problem is you can't compare an array to a string. Can someone help me about this?

here's the code

```
$subex = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D8')->getValue();
$subex2 = explode(":", $subex);

 $q = "select * from class where id='$id'";
              $r = mysql_query($q);
              $data = mysql_fetch_array($r);
              $subdat = $data['subject'];


  if($subdat == $subex2[1]) {
        echo "Data matched";

   }else {
        echo "Data doesn't matched";
   }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Cause your last bracket is `{` while it should be `}`

Comment: I already edited. Typo. But actually it has no error. But the output i expected is different. It should be matched because both values are equals. But it returned false.

Comment: Can you var_dump() both of the variables?

Comment: Yes, try adding a `var_dump($subex2);` and post the result

Comment: @RemcoK. here's the result `string(6) " IT100" string(5) "IT100"`

Comment: **The `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Stop using the [`mysql` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). It is old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Comment: You error is space in  " IT100" use trim

Comment: @axiac im just reusing the code of my client and im prevented to change the format of sql and i don't know why haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. One value has an space before it. You can solve this kind of problems like this:

```
if(trim($subdat) == trim($subex2[1])) {
    echo "Data matched";
} else {
    echo "Data doesn't matched";
}
```

for case sensitive issue, this trick should apply.

```
if(strtolower(trim($subdat)) == strtolower(trim($subex2[1]))) {
        echo "Data matched";
    } else {
        echo "Data doesn't matched";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this test works fine

```
 $subdat = "IT100";
 $subex2[1] = "IT100";


  if($subdat == $subex2[1]) {
        echo "Data matched";

   }
```

You are not comparing same string

Answer (score 0):

You first use array_map and trim values, delete space, next use in_array, example

```
$subex2 = array_map('trim',$subex2);

if( is_array($subex2) ){
     if(in_array($subdata, $subex2)){
         echo "Data matched";
      } else {
         echo "Data doesn't matched";
     }
 }
```

It's always good to check if it's actually an array, with `is_array`

Reference `in_array` https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$isMatched = strval($subex2[1]) === strval($subdat) ?: false;
```